# Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

chrome 49：
[nuxt] Error while initializing app TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function

Comment: this line is not useful to debug or help your problem

Answer (score 0):

Solution found on this [site](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n/issues/18):

- Add the es6 package to your project. https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/babel-es6-polyfill
- Add the config for the package within your Nuxt config file like so:
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build:

  ```
  vendor: [
      'babel-es6-polyfill',
  ```